# 同じパッケージ内のimport

Tags: python, python3

以下のようなディレクトリ構成で、
`main.py`から`cls_a.py`を呼び出そうと考えています。

```
pkg_a
├── __init__.py
├── cls_a.py
└── main.py
```

各ファイルの中身は以下の通りです。

- __init__.py

```py
from .cls_a import ClsA
```

- cls_a.py

```py
class ClsA:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        return 'Hello Cls A'
```

- main.py

```py
from pkg_a import ClsA
print(ClsA.hello())
```

pkg_aディレクトリから`main.py`を実行すると、pkg_aモジュールが見つからないという旨のエラーが出てしまうのですが、正常にモジュールの読み込みを行うにはどうすれば良いですか？

```
> py main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg_a import ClsA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_a'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg_a import ClsA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_a'
```

Comment: `main.py` の `from pkg_a import ClsA` を `from cls_a import ClsA` とすれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: `rom cls_a import ClsA`で上手く行きました。
しかし、\__init__.pyでpkg_a単位でのインポートを行えるように設定したつもりだったのですが、なぜうまく行かないのでしょうか？

Comment: それと、正常に動作しているにも関わらず、`from cls_a import ClsA`の**cls_a**の部分にlinterで次のようなエラーが出るのはなぜですか？`unresolved import 'cls_a'Python(unresolved-import)`

Comment: pkg_a ディレクトリの一つ上の階層(親ディレクトリ)に移動して、`python -m pkg_a.main` とするのであれば `from pkg_a import ClsA` のままでも構いません。